# App crashes when use Profiler with some errors in log

Tags: android-studio, profiler

I ran into a problem. If I just run the application through AS, then everything works fine. It enters everywhere, everything opens, all functions are performed. As soon as I try to start Profiler, the application crashes immediately after being turned on. I went to the log and noticed something like this:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10 in tid 5156 (HeapTaskDaemon), pid 5141 (d.myapplication)
```

Perhaps someone came across and can tell how to solve this problem.